# Web scraping with Selenium & read_html - Better method to get table contents? How to work with ouput of a list DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, web-scraping, format

I'm sure there is a pandas master here that can show me a better method to what I am doing. Currently, I can't simply scrape the data with read_html(), so I need to navigate the page and open the tables there by clicking on individual buttons in order to get the generated data once that happens.

code snippet;

```
elem = sesh.find_element_by_xpath(f'{gen_button}')
elem.click() #click highlight link
#get the elements from the general table
gen_table = sesh.find_element_by_xpath(body1) # go to the appropriate table
general = pd.read_html(str(gen_table.get_attribute('innerHTML')))
print(general)
```

output;

> [                       Forge FC  Minutes played  Touches 0
>   Alexander Achinioti-Jönsson              77       47 1
>   Bertrand Owundi              77       69 2             Christopher
>   Nanco              56       42 3                Dominic Samuel
>   90       59 4                 Elimane Cissé              90       75 5
>   Emery Welshman              90       51 6                Giuliano
>   Frano              90      108 7                Jonathan Grant
>   13       10 8                 Kadell Thomas              34       32 9
>   Kwame Awuah              90      108 10                  Kyle Bekker
>   90       63 11                 Marcel Zajac              13       10
>   12               Tristan Borges              90       78 13
>   Triston Henry              90       38]

You can see the table hearders are there. Followed by the index number and subsequent row...

I'm happy that it is generating the data in a way that I know I can work with. But I am surprised that the data is not scraped with any kind of delimiter, so I end up with something that at the moment is kind of unusable.

Look forward to what you can offer.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I should have realized this. That read_html creates DataFrame(S) so I will just have to make sure I load each one separately.

```
db = general[0]
a = []
for i in range(db.shape[0]):
    row = db.loc[i].values
    a.append(row)
cpl = pd.DataFrame(a,columns=['name','minutes','touches'])
```

I just feel there must be a simpler solution.